# Indexing an hastable

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell

I have an hashtable that I add to when I am creating jobs with the following code:

```
$jobtimer = @{}

1..10 | foreach {
        Start-Job -name $_ -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds (Get-Random -Minimum 456 -Maximum 46546520)
    }
    $jobtimer[$_] = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
}
```

(thank you @mjolinor for help with this by the way!!)

I then loop through my jobs and fetch time elapsed on each job. But I'm having problems reading the values of the array. If I directly reference an index it works:

```
$jobtimer[4].elapsed.totalseconds
```

But if I try to loop through my jobs and output the elapsed time I get nothing:

```
get-job | foreach { 
       echo $jobtimer[$_.name].elapsed.totalseconds
    }
```

**How do I loop through and reference my array?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you are setting you are using an integer, but for getting you are using a string ( a job's name is a string, so the jobs will have names like `"1"`, `"2"` etc and not `1`, `2`.

Either do below while setting:

```
$jobtimer["$_"] = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
```

Or do below while getting:

```
$jobtimer[[int]$_.name]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!! You wouldn't happen to know how I can echo the output without getting a new line after the variable $jobtimer?

Answer (score 2):

Add casting from string to int in accessing array:

```
get-job | foreach { $jobtimer[[int]$_.name] }
```

Comment: Thank you! I vote your answer up as well for using the correct termonology "casting" :)